# In memory file object for sftp

Tags: perl

What's the best way to do an in memory file object in perl? I'm going to want to pass it off to [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign)'s `put` method. Right now I'm just using [File::Temp](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign) as a precursor to switching to an in memory implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Perl allows you to open a file handle refering to a scalar variable instead of a real file. If Net::SFTP::Foreign supports real Perl level file handles this would work:

```
my $content = "This is the content we want to put";
open( my $fh, '<', \$content ) || die "Ooops";

$sftp->put($fh, "file.txt") or die "Ooops";
```

See the documentation for the open function in the perlfunc manual page. It is not well advertised, but it is kind of documented somewhere.

This is not guaranteed to work if Net::SFTP::Foreign is implements by a C library. But after a quick look at the module it ought to work, but I have not tested it.

Comment: I was honestly hoping for a more OOP-ish interface recommendation. maybe because I find `opens` interface awkward, (because it has side effects )

Comment: IO is mostly about side effects either way. IO::String provides a OO interface, but is a bit more awkward implementation wise and the documentation states that it is currently best for providing backwards compatibility with older perls.

Answer (score 0):

The module has an undocumented `put_content` method.

```
$sftp->put_content($content, $remote_filename, %opts);
```

Don't be afraid to use it because it is not documented, it is just that the author (that's me) forgot to document it!

BTW, under the hood, this method does what pmakholm says in his post.

Comment: the implementation seems a bit broken, I found it putting the object hashref. patches will be coming, including some more flexibility

Comment: thanks, a new version of the module with the bug solved and the method documented is now on CPAN

Comment: Still just releasing dev versions? in this case if it's going to be a dev version still next week I'll probably have to create a fix in the code I'm writing due to business needs.